# Cannot access remote server's root drive as the server's local admin

Tags: remote-access, shared-folders

On my remote server, i check that **myLogin** is a member of the Administrators Group

- verified i have both a C: and D: drive
- noted that "Admins have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain"
  [image: verify myLogin is Admin]

Next i go to another computer on my LAN and attempt to access the root D drive.

- Open up "File Explorer", in the nav bar type \\myServer\d$
- login prompt appears, login with the remote server's local account **myServer\myLogin**, which happens to be an administrator.
  [image: access hidden root drive]

Next i find that Access is denied! Whats going on? i am an Admin, surely don't need to be granted specific access?

[image: access is denied]

(incidentally i also find that StackExchange does not like PNG images, i had to convert to JPG).

Note this is within my internal LAN 192.168.x.x, I can access specific folders that i've shared.

Comment: Check the permissions of the share, even so you are in the admin group there needs to be a ach to allow the admin group.

Comment: @eckes.. No, there should be no need for explicit permissions on the shares. The c$, d$, etc shares are, after all, called admin shares, I've accessed them many times before over the years since the Windows NT days. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out i had to put in a (non-existant) registry entry at

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\

Add a new DWORD value, called it "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" and set it to 1.

Reboot required.

(Just disabling UAC and rebooting did not work for me).

Refer to:
[support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows-vista](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows-vista)
(ignore that it says Vista, applies to "myServer", which is Windows 10).